# How to replicate a a config file to different nodes in a cluster?

Tags: java, angularjs, linux, shell, distributed-computing

I am working on a college project in which I have a AngularJS app in the frontend and JAVA at the backend. I have to create a config file and replicate that file on different linux nodes Here is the flow of the application.

1) First, there is text input field in the AngularJS application in which we enter a custom IP address.

2) We have to create a .yml file with that has some static fields and a dynamic IP Address field in it. I need to edit the contents of this .yml file and change it to the IP address that was entered in step 1.

3) Next, the .yml that was created in step 2 should be sent to different Open SUSE nodes that have static IP Addresses.

How can I approach this? I am newbie.